# Linear Algebra Boldrini : Theorem 5.4.5

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T:  V → W$ a linear transformation and $α$ and $β$ basis of $V$ and $W$ respectively.
I want to show that $dim Im T =$ rank of matrix transformation $T$ on this basis and that $dim ker T =$ nullity of matrix transformation $T$ on this basis.
I tried using $dim V = dim Im T + dim ker T$ but I could not finish what I need.

Comment: I am a little unfamiliar with the terminology and notation that you are using. Are you familiar with the rank-nullity theorem? It seems similar and/or useful.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to prove the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem)

Comment: The rank-nullity theorem says $dim ker T + dim Im T = dim V$? If yes. The theorem I am referring to is different.

Comment: The english word for "posto" is rank, not "post". It's ok to study with Boldrini's book, but you should take a look in any book in english, just to get used to more terminology.